# Gerar um array dentro do XML no sql server

Tags: sql, xml

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou executando uma Procedure no Sql Sever que me gera um XML através do comando XML PATH, porém, um dos campos é um array, o que eu consegui foi isso:

**Este select está dentro da PROC que é o que interessa para gerar o XML:**

```
<font face="Courier New" size="2">
<font color = "blue">SELECT</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_priority</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">&quot;@ID&quot;</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_number</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_type</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_priority</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_name</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_phone</font><font color = "silver">=</font><font color = "#FF0080"><b>Isnull</b></font><font color = "maroon">(</font><font color = "maroon">order_client_phone</font><font color = "silver">,</font>&nbsp;<font color = "red">''</font><font color = "maroon">)</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_code</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_cpf_cnpj</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_address</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_address_number</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_complement</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_district</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_city</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "fuchsia"><i>Upper</i></font><font color = "maroon">(</font><font color = "maroon">order_client_state</font><font color = "maroon">)</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_state</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_client_cep</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_exped_name</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_exped_field</font><font color = "silver">=</font><font color = "#FF0080"><b>Isnull</b></font><font color = "maroon">(</font><font color = "maroon">order_exped_field</font><font color = "silver">,</font>&nbsp;<font color = "red">''</font><font color = "maroon">)</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_exped_date</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_erpwms</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_invoices</font><font color = "silver">,</font>
<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_items</font>
<br/><font color = "blue">FROM</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">#temp</font>
<br/><font color = "blue">WHERE</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_priority</font>&nbsp;<font color = "silver">&lt;</font>&nbsp;<font color = "black">999</font>
<br/><font color = "blue">ORDER</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = "blue">BY</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">order_priority</font>
<br/><font color = "blue">FOR</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">xml</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">path</font><font color = "maroon">(</font><font color = "red">'Order'</font><font color = "maroon">)</font><font color = "silver">,</font>&nbsp;<font color = "maroon">root</font><font color = "maroon">(</font><font color = "red">'Customers'</font><font color = "maroon">)</font>&nbsp;
</font>
```

**O resultado é:**

[image: XML1]

Porém o que preciso seria, onde é o campo **order_invoices** o XML ficasse da seguinte maneira:

[image: xml2]

Alguém poderia me ajudar com algumas dicas e sugestões de como conseguir este resultado? Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não seria algo assim que você quer?

```
SELECT order_priority" @ID",
       <br/>order_number, 
       <br/>order_type,
       <br/>order_priority, 
       <br/>order_client_name, 
       <br/>order_client_phone=Isnull(order_client_phone, ''), 
       <br/>order_client_code, 
       <br/>order_client_cpf_cnpj, 
       <br/>order_client_address, 
       <br/>order_client_address_number, 
       <br/>order_client_complement, 
       <br/>order_client_district, 
       <br/>order_client_city, 
       <br/>Upper(order_client_state) order_client_state, 
       <br/>order_client_cep, 
       <br/>order_exped_name, 
       <br/>order_exped_field=Isnull(order_exped_field, ''), 
       <br/>order_exped_date, 
       <br/>order_erpwms, 
       <br/>invoice_number AS "order_invoices/invoice_number", 
       <br/>invoice_serie AS "order_invoices/invoice_serie", 
       <br/>invoice_danfe AS "order_invoices/invoice_danfe", 
       <br/>invoice_value AS "order_invoices/invoice_value", 
       <br/>invoice_ERPWMS AS "order_invoices/invoice_ERPWMS", 
       <br/>order_items 
<br/>FROM   #temp 
<br/>WHERE  order_priority < 999 
<br/>ORDER  BY order_priority 
<br/>FOR xml path('Order'), root('Customers')
```

Comment: Sua resposta satisfaz a minha pergunta, anteriormente havia conseguido usando essa query:

Comment: No caso o campo invoice_ERPWMS há mais de resultado, as outras linhas estão se repetindo por causa disso, você saberia uma maneira de eu agrupar para somente o invoice_ERPWMS se repetir as outras linhas não?

Comment: Já resolvi essa minha dúvida!

Answer (score 2):

**Consegui dessa forma também:**
 @André Callazzans
[image: img1]